# Vue routing dynamic

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a backoffice in Laravel with dynamic routes, however, I don't know how I do this in vue js, that is, create routes dynamically, so that a controller or something like that returns me the correct view!

Comment: You could try using the 'addRoutes' method? https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes

Comment: in laravel I have 
`Route :: get ('/ {slug}', 'FrontController @ resolver') -> middleware ('ttl: 60');`
and needed something like that for vue

Comment: So you're saying you need a route with a dynamic parameter, like {slug}?

Comment: yes, as I represent the code above in the vue routes, that redirects me to a controller or something where I can tell which view to present

Answer (score 0):

Small example for you.

**Laravel part**
Your "web" routes in Laravel

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'AppController')->where('any', '.*');
```

Inside invoke controller

```
public function __invoke()
    {
        return view('app');
    }
```

In app.blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div id="app">
    <app/>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Vuejs part:**

Your router file

```
import Login from "./views/Login";
import Home from "./views/Home";
import NotFound from "./views/NotFound";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/login', name: 'login', component: Login },
        { path: "/", name: 'home', component: Home },
        { path: "*", name: '404', component: NotFound }
});
```

In app.js

```
import router from './router';

const app = new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    i18n,
    el: '#app',
});
```

All post, put, patch routes should be "api" routes.

Comment: if i add a new route in the backoffice do i have to add it manually in the vue's route file?

Comment: In Laravel you have only one route with where('any', '*') - this for all your views (GET methods)
But in Vue router you need add all your views and assign unique path for each and Vue route will show needed view by path.

Comment: in laravel I have `Route :: get ('/ {slug}', 'FrontController @ resolver') -> middleware ('ttl: 60');` and needed something like that for vue

Answer (score 0):

You could try Vue Router's Dynamic Route matching, passing different values for route parameters: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html